# How to detect if previous screen or Activity was a WebView or BrowserActivity ? (Android)

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview

I have a very simple question - **Is there any way to detect if previous screen or Activity was a WebView or a BrowserActivity** (e.g. LinkedIn Authentication page etc.) ?

Suppose I have **Activity A** and **Activity B** . I start Activity B from Activity A. Now from Activity B, I start a **WebView or BrowserActivity** (in my case LinkedIn Authentication page). So user can go back to Activity B from this WebView.  So we can go to Activity B from 2 different screens - either from Activity A or from WebView. **I just want to know if I have come on Activity B from Activity A or that WebView .**

I have searched a lot about it but can't find anything. I am afraid if its not even possible. Please help.

Comment: Can we have some code please !?

Comment: What kind of code ? Its just a general question.

Comment: Its not good idea to ask question without any single try !!!!

Comment: brother, I have been trying for last 2 days. I am a member of SO for around 7 months now. So I understand the rules. My scenario is quite vast , so I just want to know if its possible or not. I don't want any spoon-feeding.

Comment: How do you mean 'previous screen' ?

Comment: @Alex : Please see the edits in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What if you put some extra data into the `Intent` which starts `Activity B` when you start it from `Activity A`. Then in B's `onCreate` you will be able to check if those data exist and, if yes, you can assume B was started from A.

You also can start an Activity C from B with `startActivityForResult`. Then you will know that you are back in B from C when your B's `onActivityResult` is called (you will have to check the request id)